# C# Генератор случайных чисел с GUI

Tags: c#, gui

Проблема с выводом случайных чисел в текстовое поле. То есть макс и мин в Gui(текстфилд) вводишь, все окей, но как определить длину ключа? то есть ввести  в поле, например, 13 и получить на выходе 13 случайных целых чисел в одну строку. На словах это все окей), но вот как это все оформить красивенько в плане кода?))

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Заранее спасибо:)))

Comment: цикл вам в помощь

Comment: А можно поточнее чтобы более понятно было?))))Ато не особо доходит))

Comment: C помощью чего я могу читать данные,которые были введены в поле для длинны ключа?

Comment: А как вы читали мах & min? Свойство `Text` у соотв. текстбокса дает вам введенное значение. С помощью `int.TryParse()` вы сможете из `string` получить `int`.

Comment: Читал через random.Next(Convert.ToInt32(MinGen.Text), Convert.ToInt32(MaxGen.Text)).ToString();

Comment: так а в чем проблема это 13 раз запустить?

Comment: Мне надо чтобы программка прочитала в текстовом поле число то, и вывела мне в текстовое поле с пом. кнопки generate n-колличество целых чисел.

Comment: ну вам же написали - используйте цикл для этого.

Comment: Можете, пожалуйста, детальней обьяснить?мне как-то трудно доходит если честно)Как мне сконвертировать ответ в кол. цифр и как сген. с ответа кол. цифр, равное даному ответу?Заранее спасибо:)

Comment: ну что то типа `for(int i=0; i<int.Parse(someTextBox.Text); i++) outTextBox.Text += random.Next(Convert.ToInt32(MinGen.Text), Convert.ToInt32(MaxGen.Text)).ToString() + Environment.NewLine;` - это решение "в лоб", если хотите элегантного и производительного решения, то придется самому таки напрячься :)

Comment: Спасибо вам большое)Да меня хотя бы направить в правильную сторону,а там уже сам попробую разобраться)

Comment: Блин, c  Environment.NewLine идет вывод с каждой новой строки у меня. Как мне сгенерировать например такую последовательность: 3 43 123 456 34 78?

Comment: Может уже сначала почитаете доки по языку, или там какой-нибудь учебник? Почему мы должны отвечать на фундаментальные вопросы которые элементарно есть в каждой книжке по языку и/или элементарно гуглятся?

Answer (score 1):

[image: Вы хотите что-то похожее?]

Код очень простой, свойство AppendText добавляет в конец текста еще текст в этом поле(у вас это TextBox, верно?). Сам код:

```
private void BtnRandom_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            int n;
            n = Rnd.Next(Convert.ToInt32(numericUpDown1.Value),Convert.ToInt32(numericUpDown2.Value)+1);
            lblRandom.Text = n.ToString();
            if (rndSwitch.Checked)
            {
                while (tbRandom.Text.IndexOf(n.ToString()) == -1)
                tbRandom.AppendText(n + " \n");
            }
            else tbRandom.AppendText(n + " \n");
        }
```